# Customize facebook share button with bootstrap style

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

How could I apply bootstrap style on the facebook share button?

I   change the share link with this JS dynamically

```
$scope.$on('fbShareLinkChanged', function(e, d) {
  $scope.fbShareLink = d
  $scope.fbShareBtnTemplate = '<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="'+ d+ '" data-layout="icon_link" data-mobile-iframe="true""> </div>　'

});
```

However, I found the button style could not be changed.

I want to use bootstrap style with text "Share with your friends"

How could I do?

[image: inline]
DEMO page https://lazyair.co/user/quick_search/index#/?depart_date_range=2016%2F05%2F09%20-%202016%2F05%2F17&return_date_range=2016%2F06%2F14%20-%202016%2F06%2F17&from=OKINAWA&to=TAIPEI (the button will show when you change any dropdown item)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

HTML

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" title="Share on  
Facebook" target="_blank" class="btn btn-facebook"><i class="fa 
fa-facebook"></i> Share with your friends</a>
```

CSS

```
.btn-facebook {
background: #3b5998;
border-radius: 3px;
color: #fff;
padding: 8px 16px;
}

.btn-facebook:link, .btn-facebook:visited {
color: #fff;
}

.btn-facebook:active, .btn-facebook:hover {
background: #30477a;
color: #fff;
}
```

I would basically add in the classes for the style, and change the element from "div" to "a" element.

```
$scope.fbShareBtnTemplate = '<a class="btn btn-facebook" data-href="'+ d + '" data-layout="icon_link" data-mobile
-iframe="true"> <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Share with your friends</a>'
```

Please see

https://jsfiddle.net/h5472odv/

**Note:** this requires Fontawesome